# Directed Graph/Hierarchy SQl

Tags: sql, teradata, hierarchical-data, directed-graph

We have below data from upstream:-

```
child. Parent
2.      1
3.      1
14.     1
1.      4
5.      1
6.      7
8.      7
13.     8
12.     8
8.      13
9.      10
10.     11
```

sometimes, child appears in parent and vice versa, there is no set order and relations can be cylic too.

Expected output is

```
child.  group
1.       1
2.       1
3.       1
4.       1
5.       1
6.       1
7.       1
8.       1
12.      1
13.      1

9.       10
10.      10
11.      10
```

can someone suggest the possible solutions, i have tried directed sql but cyclic relations are being excluded

Comment: Are you trying to group all children with the same parent to a `group` id?  And I assume the `group` id is the # of children belonging to the parent, is that right?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reaching out, yes trying to group all childrens under one group and group id can be anything....here i have choosen one of the childrens as a group id, idea is to use them together one they are identified as a group.

Comment: OK, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Cycles make this a pain.  One method is to store the values that have been visited in a string.  So, the idea is to get every possible matching value and then aggregate -- the minimum match is a good descriptor for the "group":

```
with recursive cp as (
      select child as node1, child as node2
      from t
      union  -- remove duplicates
      select parent, parent
      from t
     ),
     cte as (
      select node1, node2, '|' || node1 || '|' as nodes
      from cp
      union all
      select cte.node1, cp.node2, cte.nodes || cte.node1 || '|'
      from cte join
           cp
           on cp.node2 = cte.node1
      where cte.nodes not like '%|' || cp.node1 || '|%'
     )
select cte.node1, min(cte.node2)
from cte
group by cte.node1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, let me try this and get back to you!

Comment: This gives error as Non Recursive with clause or view should not  reference itself within its own definition

Comment: @Zishan . . . Perhaps you need to have `recursive` before `cte` for that definition.

Comment: Thanks, i did try that but it had issues too, maybe i will store CP results in a temp table and call it within recursive cte to see how it works....will keep posted.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte (child, parent) AS (

  -- Seed rows (initial relationships)
  SELECT child, parent, 0 AS depth
  FROM mytable 

  UNION ALL

  -- Get children
  SELECT mytable.child, mytable.parent, depth + 1 AS newdepth
  FROM cte 
  INNER JOIN mytable ON cte.child = mytable.parent -- Get child row if also a parent
  WHERE newdepth <= 20 -- Avoid possible infinite recursion
)
SELECT 
  child, 
  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY parent DESC) AS group -- Common group ID for rows with same parent
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT child, parent FROM cte -- Get rid of duplicates
) src
```

Replace `mytable` with your table name.  You may also need to rename `group` to another name, if you get a keyword error.

Give it a try and let me know.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c904a/19)

Comment: this has formed 3 groups for group 1, i will paste the detailed results later